# How to get input value without id

Tags: javascript, jquery

what I want to do is something like when user finished typing my app shows a message of the value typed in that input, I will have a lot of inputs so it's not an option doing by selecting input ID, so how can I solve this problem? What I'm trying to do is selecting `$(this).value` but I only get "undefinied", here is an example code of what I'm trying to do

```js
var timer = null;
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('input').keydown(function (event) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(validarType, 1000)
    });


});
function validarType() {
    var xd = $(this).value;
    alert(xd);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text"/>
```

Comment: let me see the rest of your dom, you can use parent/child relationship to get the input if there is more than 1 input on the page.

Comment: Why not pass the value into your validator method, its more re-usable then. Use an anonymous function in the timeout to call your validator method with the value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code isn't working for 2 reasons

`this` isn't the same `this` as it was when your handler was called - because you're calling this function from within a timeout.

`$(this)` is a jQuery object - there is no `value` attribute

Correct code:

```
var timer = null;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input').keydown(function (event) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(validarType.bind(this), 1000) //bind the existing context
    });
});
function validarType() {
    var xd = this.value; //this is now a regular DOM element - and has a value attribute
    alert(xd);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend!